# hibernate 4 spring 4: On Lazy loading - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread

Tags: spring, hibernate, java-8, migrating

I added aspect advice to lazy loading for init session.
After migrating to Spring 4, Hibernate 4, Java 8 got exception:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

Hibernate config:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="reattachSessionAspect" class="prj.ReattachSessionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            // model packages
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_statement</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Aspect class (exception caused by sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()):

```
@Aspect
public class Aspect {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    private static ThreadLocal<Boolean> LOCK = new ThreadLocal<Boolean>();

    @Around("reattachSession()")
    public Object reattachSession(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        Object obj = pjp.proceed();
        if (obj instanceof AbstractPersistentCollection) {
            AbstractPersistentCollection ps = (AbstractPersistentCollection) obj;
            Field field = getClass(ps.getClass()).getDeclaredField("session");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            SessionImpl o = (SessionImpl)field.get(ps);
            if (!ps.wasInitialized() && (o == null || o.isClosed()) && (LOCK.get()==null || !LOCK.get())) {
                LOCK.set(true);
                Transaction t = null;
                try {
                    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                    t = session.beginTransaction();
                    session.update(pjp.getTarget());
                    Hibernate.initialize(ps);
                    session.getTransaction().commit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    if (t != null && t.isActive()) {
                        t.rollback();
                    }
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } finally {
                    LOCK.set(false);
                }
            }
        }
        return  obj;
    }

    private Class getClass(Class clazz) {
        if(clazz.equals(AbstractPersistentCollection.class)){
            return clazz;
        } else {
            return getClass(clazz.getSuperclass());
        }
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(@prj.AddSession * *(..))")
    public void reattachSession(){
    }
}
```

Method that cause exception when called:

```
@Lazy
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public List<Detail> getDetails() {
        return details;
    }
```

In services layers session getting right. And before migrating all worked. Before migrating i had current_session_context_class=thread.

Can someone advise me what i doing wrong ?